# Jaxb combine xmls

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm reading an xml file using Jaxb, now the contents of the xml file are increasing and the file is becoming too cumbersome to maintain, is there any way I can modularize the xml, by splitting it into multiple files? Is there anyway to do this in a simpler way in jaxb ?

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit ? I'm reading that you would like to split the XML file, but not necessarily the JAXB class. The posters  below seem to read your question the other way. Maybe you could rephrase a bit ?

Comment: @PatriceM. : Exactly, I would like to split the xml file, without splitting the JAXB class. Something like modularizing struts-config.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yo could use the tried-and-true (yet much-disliked) ENTITY method in your XML file, e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE config [
  <!ENTITY subpart1 SYSTEM 'config_subpart1.xml'>
  <!ENTITY subpart2 SYSTEM 'config_subpart2.xml'>
]>
<config>
    <!-- some top-level config items in the main file
    <item1>value</item1>
    ...
    <!-- then the external parts -->
    &subpart1;
    ...
    &subpart2;
    ...
</config>
```

The XML document is technically identical, and your JAXB code should work without any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can read a large xml document chunk by chunk.

http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Dealing_with_large_documents.html 
This JAXB doc says there are some example in JAXB RI distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of STAX and JAXB. Use STAX to reach the element you want to read and then map the element to object using JAXB. That way you would be reading only the element required into the object. You need to design and manage your schema intelligently.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing my own [XmlAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html) that adapts my `LargeObject` to special `LazyLargeObjectLoader`. Thus the main XML file only stores a reference to the large object's xml file (as a string) and the lazy loader loads the actual object from its own file when I request it.

This solution works well in my experience as it avoids storing everything in memory at once.